# JQuery JavaScript Error in Browser, Not Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm trying to create a webpage that takes a location via a text box, and plots all recent earthquakes near that location on Google Maps.

I'm using Dreamweaver to debug my code, and the webpage works perfectly when I use the built-in live webpage feature it includes.

However, when I open the saved file in a browser, all I get is an error **"Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ERROR"**. This isn't exactly helpful for figuring out what the issue is, and I have very little experience with web languages and developing web sites.

Any help or insight you can lend me would be greatly appreciated.

---

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&sensor=true">
    </script>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }


        function codeAddress() 
        {
            var loc = document.getElementById('locText').value;

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': loc}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                    var north = results[0].geometry.location.lat() + 1;
                    var south = results[0].geometry.location.lat() - 1;
                    var east  = results[0].geometry.location.lng() + 1;
                    var west  = results[0].geometry.location.lng() - 1;

                    var url;

                    url = 'http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=' + north + '&south=' + south + '&east=' + east + '&west=' + west + '&username=jpcguy89';

                    $.ajax(url,function(quakes)
                    {
                        $.each(quakes.earthquakes, function(k, aQuake){

                            var contentString = '<div id="content">' + '<p><b>ID:</b> ' + aQuake.eqid + '</p>' + '<p><b>Magnitude:</b> ' + aQuake.magnitude + '<p><b>Date:</b> ' + aQuake.datetime + '<p><b>Depth:</b> ' + aQuake.depth + '</div>';

                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                            ({
                                 content: contentString
                            });

                            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(aQuake.lat,aQuake.lng);

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                            ({
                                position: latLng,
                                map: map,
                                title: 'Earthquake (' + aQuake.eqid + ')'
                            });


                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
                            {
                                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                            }); 
                        });     
                    });
                }

                else 
                {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>
<body>
<br />
<br />
<div id="test"></div>
<br />
<br />

<form id="geonamesFetch">
    City/Location: <input type="text" id="locText" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="codeAddress()" />
</form>
<div id="map-canvas"/>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mZGL3/

Comment: Which browsers are showing this error?

Comment: Does this happen all the time, or only with certain locations?

Comment: Protocols ! Just watch for your protocols. :: seen on jsFiddle : Timestamp: 9/30/2013 3:40:41 PM
Error: ReferenceError: google is not defined
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mZGL3/show/
Line: 93

Comment: Are you opening this as `file://` and not from a server?

Comment: Browser's showing the error are Safari, and Chrome. I am running this as a file://, NOT from a server (I was unable to open it using my ip or localhost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the click handler in the HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="codeAddress()" />
```

Done this way, the JavaScript is executed, but then the form is immediately submitted.  You need to prevent the form from submitting.  Remove the click handler from the html:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

And bind to the submit handler in your JavaScript so that you can prevent the form from submitting.  Add this to your JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#geonamesFetch").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        codeAddress();
    });
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/mZGL3/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mZGL3/3/)

**Edit:** The other problem you have is your call to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax).  That method expects an object, but you are passing a function.  You can either change your code to pass an object, setting the function you have now as the `success` property:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    success: function(quakes) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Or use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get), which accepts a function as the second argument:

```
$.get(url, function (quakes) {
    ...
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/mZGL3/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/mZGL3/4/)

Comment: This fixed half the issue (and thanks, because that's a big help!). It's still not showing the markers, however. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jpcguy89 - Change `$.ajax()` to `$.get()`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be loading mixed protocol ressources.

And your jsFiddle seems to have a ressource missing (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&sensor=true)

Fix your code to access NON httpS .. and try again.

Seen on your jsFiddle :

```
> Timestamp: 9/30/2013 3:40:41 PM Error: ReferenceError: google is not
> defined Source File: fiddle.jshell.net/mZGL3/show Line: 93
```

I updated your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mZGL3/1/), with the ressource, now, the error is : {"error": "Please use POST request"}